# Identify this Fuji

Tags: identify-this-bike

My friend rented this bike some time ago, liked it, and wants to know what kind of bike it is. It is clearly a Fuji, but can anyone be more specific? Apologies in advance, I only have this one photo.[image]

Comment: Cross bikes route the cables above the top tube so you can run with the bike on your shoulder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a cyclocross frame and a 52/34 compact drivetrain (tiagra? Sora?) and fat tires (32's?), so likely a **[Fuji Tread](https://www.performancebike.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/ProductDisplay?storeId=10052&langId=-1&catalogId=10551&productId=1192391&utm_source=Google_Product_Search&utm_medium=pla&utm_campaign=datafeed&cm_mmc=Google_Product_Search-_-PLA-_-Datafeed-_-Fuji%20Tread%201.3%20Disc%20Road%20Bike%20-%202016%20Grey%2048&CAWELAID=400006950000106795&CAGPSPN=pla&CAAGID=25577014563&CATCI=pla-157198228803&catargetid=400006950000108164&cadevice=c&gclid=CIqTvpm_kNQCFUlNfgod3_MKLg)** gravel bike. I just wrecked one (my pride and joy) yesterday.

This is a Fuji Tread 2.0 LE
[image: Bike before I crashed it]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a road biker, but it looks to me like a [Fuji Absolute 1.1](https://www.bike-discount.de/de/kaufen/fuji-absolute-1.1-561036?delivery_country=48&gclid=CJO6lJG3kNQCFVOZGwodbnEAWg) from 2013ish.

Comment: The cable routing is off -- all the cables are above the toptube.